# how to find the near number to make zero remainder for a quotient?

Tags: number-theory

There is an expression A*x/B, where A and B are given constant (positive integer), x is also positive integer and initially given but I am trying to find the next integer such that A*x is multiple integer of B. Now I can only use a program to search for that

```
for newx = x to x+10000
  if (mod(newx*A, B)==0)
    x = newx
    exit for
  end if 
end for
```

You see that I consider a big range from x to x+10000 to search for the number, but if there is any mathematical to solve for that instead of using program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A and B are given constant. the fraction $\frac{Ax}{B}$ we can divide both A and B by their GCD. We'll end up with $\frac{A_1x}{B_1}$, such as $GCD(A_1,B_1) = 1$. If $B_1$ is 1 then for every x we'll get an integer. Otherwise because $GCD(A_1,B_1) = 1$ implies that $B_1|x$ in order to get an integer solution. So the smallest integer solution for $x$ is $B_1$ and the next number is $2B_1$. And for given x, the next solution bigger than x is given by: $$\lceil\frac{x}{B_1}\rceil \times B_1$$

---

If we want x to be a multiple of 8, then we just solve this equation.

$$\left( \lceil\frac{x}{B_1}\rceil + y \right) \times B_1 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$

Beacuse we know the the values for $x$ and $B_1$ this should be easy. Here's one example:

**x = 124, $B_1$ = 14**

$$\left( \lceil\frac{124}{14}\rceil + y \right) \times 14 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$
$$(9 + y) \times 6 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$
$$54 + 6y \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$
$$6y \equiv 2 \equiv 18 \pmod 8$$
$$y \equiv 3 \pmod 8$$

So we chose the smallest integer y that satisfy this condition and that's $y=3$

So the first smallest solution of the form $8k$ that is bigger than initially given $x$ is:

$$\left( \lceil\frac{124}{14}\rceil + 3 \right) \times 14 = 12 \times 14 = 168$$

---

The solution to this equation will give you x.

$$\left( \lceil\frac{x+p}{B_1}\rceil + y \right) \times B_1 \equiv p \pmod 8$$

It'll be clearer with example:

**x = 124, $B_1$ = 14, p = 22**

$$\left( \lceil\frac{124+22}{14}\rceil + y \right) \times 14 \equiv 22 \pmod 8$$
$$(11 + y) \times 6 \equiv 6 \pmod 8$$
$$66 + 6y \equiv 6 \pmod 8$$
$$6y \equiv -60 \equiv 4 \equiv 12 \pmod 8$$
$$y \equiv 2 \pmod 8$$

We take $y=2$

$$\left( \lceil\frac{124+22}{14}\rceil + 2 \right) \times 14 = 13 \times 14 = 182$$

Now we have $x+p = 182$, which isn't divisible by 8, but we know that $p=22$, so we obtain $x=160$, which is a multiple of 8.

Note that sometimes it won't work. One example is when $B_1$ is even and $p$ is odd, whihc will lead to:

$$\text{even number} \equiv \text{odd number} \pmod 8 \text{, which is impossible}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry to put that but I forgot to stay that I would like the next number of x is the multiple integer of 8. Is any easy way to modify your expression a bit to fit that?

Comment: This version gives the least $x$, rather than the least $x$ beyond some fixed starting value of $x$ said to be "initially given" in OP.

Comment: Can you check the edit and comment your opinion about it?

Comment: Stefan4024-- Now it looks right, and also addresses the issue about divisibility by 8.

Comment: Hope that @user1285419 will be pleased with it. ;)

Comment: Hi Stefan, the math looks pretty neat, thanks. I am learning the math but to my understand, y is the offset such that it will give the expect answer. So can I said that if I want to find x such that A*(x+p)/B is integer and x dividable by 8 (not x+p), can I replace y in your equation with y+p and solve for y, right?

Comment: Hope this will help you. Check the edit

Comment: Thank you so much. I learn something :)

Answer (score 1):

Let your given numbers $A,B$ be each divided by their gcd first, but still call them $A,B$. (Note this doesn't change the value of any fractions $Ax/B$) Then with your given $x$, assuming $Ax/B$ is not already an integer, define $m$ to be the ceiling of $x/B$, and then put $mB-x=k$. Then $x+k$ will be the first integer after $x$ for which $Ax/B$ is an integer.

Example: $A=35,B=55,x=100$. First reset $A=5,B=11$ (divide by gcd step). Then compute ceiling of $x/B=100/11$ which gives our $m=10$, and finally compute $mb-x=10\cdot 11-100=10$ This means that $x+k=100+10=110$ is the first number after $100$ that works. Check that indeed $35\cdot 110/55=70,$ and for $x$ between $100$ and $110$ you get fractions.

Comment: Thanks coffeemath, I read your post and I think it is the one I am looking for to get the next number satisfy. But again, I want to find the next x (next to the given number) satisfying the condition and dividable by 8. Should it work by just replacing B with 8*B?

Comment: @user1285419 The divisible by 8 issue is treated OK in Stefan's answer above, so I see no need to add to my version, which is basically equivalent anyway. But note that one approach to this issue is just to initially replace the number $B$ (after gcd has been removed) by $8B$, in case $A$ is odd.